# How to ordered a data coming from the JSON response and load in table in a predefine sequence

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I need your help to parse a response coming from the API and update the table section and row based on the key "deck" order preference.

Right now I'm making a Dictionary of key value by grouping the similar type of "deck" but after grouping the deck sequence coming from the response is change and resulting in an unordered dictionary.

**Here is my code:**

```
func hitGetDVLData(dataDict: NSDictionary) {
    APIsHandler.getDVLVideos(postData: dataDict) { (result, response, error, errorMessage) in
        if let responseData = response {
            if( error == nil && (responseData["status"] as AnyObject) as? Bool ?? false){
                if let responseData1 = responseData["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                    self.courseDataDict = responseData1 as! [String : Any]
                    if let topics = (responseData1["curriculam"] as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "topics") as? [[String : Any]] {
                        // attached output below
                    
                        self.totalArrayCount = topics.count
                        let crossReference = Dictionary(grouping: topics, by: { $0["deck"] as! String })
                        
                        self.premimumVideoArray = [:]
                        self.premimumVideoArray =  crossReference
                        // attached output below
                    }

                self.tableviewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableViewHeight
                self.tableView.reloadData()
               
               } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where courseDataDict & premimumVideoArray is a variable defines as below

```
var courseDataDict: [String : Any] = [:]

var premimumVideoArray : [String : [[String:Any]]] = [:]
```

**OUTPUT:**

***response:***

```
{
    data =     {
        "course_type" = 4;
        "cover_image" = "https://dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/course_file_meta/8fa5367315f2b063d45c165095d5f4f4";
        "cover_video" = "";
        curriculam =         {
            title = "";
            topics =             (
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Preclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1513449anatomy.png";
                    title = Anatomy;
                    "topic_id" = 2243;
                    total = 47;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Preclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1524143physiology.png";
                    title = Physiology;
                    "topic_id" = 2421;
                    total = 59;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Preclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/3658439biochemistry.png";
                    title = Biochemistry;
                    "topic_id" = 2245;
                    total = 35;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Paraclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5903031pathalogy.png";
                    title = Pathology;
                    "topic_id" = 2419;
                    total = 97;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Paraclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7011603pharmocology.png";
                    title = Pharmacology;
                    "topic_id" = 2412;
                    total = 95;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Paraclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5728715microbilogy.png";
                    title = Microbiology;
                    "topic_id" = 2411;
                    total = 90;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Paraclinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468554forensic.png";
                    title = FMT;
                    "topic_id" = 2416;
                    total = 8;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = "Clinicals (Prefinals)";
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/6417172ophthalmology.png";
                    title = Ophthalmology;
                    "topic_id" = 2418;
                    total = 51;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = "Clinicals (Prefinals)";
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1909654ent.png";
                    title = ENT;
                    "topic_id" = 2420;
                    total = 62;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = "Clinicals (Prefinals)";
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5293280community_medicine.png";
                    title = PSM;
                    "topic_id" = 2409;
                    total = 26;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Clinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5520806medicine.png";
                    title = Medicine;
                    "topic_id" = 2637;
                    total = 137;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Clinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5084703surgery.png";
                    title = Surgery;
                    "topic_id" = 2638;
                    total = 83;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Clinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "";
                    title = "Obg&Gy";
                    "topic_id" = 2423;
                    total = 41;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = Clinicals;
                    "sub_img_url" = "";
                    title = Paediatrics;
                    "topic_id" = 2246;
                    total = 27;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = SARPO;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/462645dermatology.png";
                    title = Dermatology;
                    "topic_id" = 2415;
                    total = 27;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = SARPO;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7845414anesthysia.png";
                    title = Anesthesia;
                    "topic_id" = 2639;
                    total = 22;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = SARPO;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468718radiology.png";
                    title = Radiology;
                    "topic_id" = 2406;
                    total = 31;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = SARPO;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2301599psychiatry.png";
                    title = Psychiatry;
                    "topic_id" = 2410;
                    total = 26;
                },
                                {
                    completed = "";
                    deck = SARPO;
                    "sub_img_url" = "http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2994784orthopendics.png";
                    title = Orthopaedics;
                    "topic_id" = 2414;
                    total = 35;
                }
            );
        };
        "desc_header_image" = "https://dams-apps-production.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/course_file_meta/7661839dvl.png";
        "for_dams" = 80000;
        "free_ids" = "78295,28,59809,176600,231590,164118,181331,230458,3066";
        gst = 18;
        "gst_include" = 1;
        id = 451;
        "is_purchased" = 1;
        "is_validity" = 0;
        learner = 21;
        mrp = 0;
        "non_dams" = 80000;
        "points_conversion_rate" = 100;
        rating = "0.0";
        "review_count" = 0;
        title = DVL;
        validity = 0;
    };
    error =     (
    );
    "is_ios_price" = 1;
    message = "Course information.";
    status = 1;
}
```

***topics:***

```
[["title": Anatomy, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1513449anatomy.png, "completed": , "topic_id": 2243, "deck": Preclinicals, "total": 47], ["total": 59, "title": Physiology, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1524143physiology.png, "completed": , "topic_id": 2421, "deck": Preclinicals], ["total": 35, "deck": Preclinicals, "completed": , "title": Biochemistry, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/3658439biochemistry.png, "topic_id": 2245], ["total": 97, "title": Pathology, "completed": , "topic_id": 2419, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5903031pathalogy.png, "deck": Paraclinicals], ["topic_id": 2412, "total": 95, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7011603pharmocology.png, "completed": , "title": Pharmacology, "deck": Paraclinicals], ["deck": Paraclinicals, "total": 90, "completed": , "title": Microbiology, "topic_id": 2411, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5728715microbilogy.png], ["sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468554forensic.png, "deck": Paraclinicals, "total": 8, "title": FMT, "completed": , "topic_id": 2416], ["topic_id": 2418, "deck": Clinicals (Prefinals), "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/6417172ophthalmology.png, "title": Ophthalmology, "total": 51, "completed": ], ["title": ENT, "total": 62, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1909654ent.png, "topic_id": 2420, "completed": , "deck": Clinicals (Prefinals)], ["deck": Clinicals (Prefinals), "total": 26, "completed": , "topic_id": 2409, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5293280community_medicine.png, "title": PSM], ["title": Medicine, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5520806medicine.png, "topic_id": 2637, "total": 137, "deck": Clinicals, "completed": ], ["title": Surgery, "deck": Clinicals, "topic_id": 2638, "total": 83, "completed": , "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5084703surgery.png], ["topic_id": 2423, "sub_img_url": , "deck": Clinicals, "title": Obg&Gy, "completed": , "total": 41], ["sub_img_url": , "topic_id": 2246, "title": Paediatrics, "deck": Clinicals, "completed": , "total": 27], ["title": Dermatology, "completed": , "deck": SARPO, "total": 27, "topic_id": 2415, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/462645dermatology.png], ["deck": SARPO, "total": 22, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7845414anesthysia.png, "completed": , "title": Anesthesia, "topic_id": 2639], ["topic_id": 2406, "total": 31, "title": Radiology, "deck": SARPO, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468718radiology.png, "completed": ], ["title": Psychiatry, "total": 26, "topic_id": 2410, "deck": SARPO, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2301599psychiatry.png, "completed": ], ["deck": SARPO, "completed": , "topic_id": 2414, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2994784orthopendics.png, "title": Orthopaedics, "total": 35]]
```

***crossReference:***

```
["Paraclinicals": [["total": 97, "title": Pathology, "completed": , "topic_id": 2419, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5903031pathalogy.png, "deck": Paraclinicals], ["topic_id": 2412, "total": 95, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7011603pharmocology.png, "completed": , "title": Pharmacology, "deck": Paraclinicals], ["deck": Paraclinicals, "total": 90, "completed": , "title": Microbiology, "topic_id": 2411, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5728715microbilogy.png], ["sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468554forensic.png, "deck": Paraclinicals, "total": 8, "title": FMT, "completed": , "topic_id": 2416]], "Clinicals (Prefinals)": [["topic_id": 2418, "deck": Clinicals (Prefinals), "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/6417172ophthalmology.png, "title": Ophthalmology, "total": 51, "completed": ], ["title": ENT, "total": 62, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1909654ent.png, "topic_id": 2420, "completed": , "deck": Clinicals (Prefinals)], ["deck": Clinicals (Prefinals), "total": 26, "completed": , "topic_id": 2409, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5293280community_medicine.png, "title": PSM]], "SARPO": [["title": Dermatology, "completed": , "deck": SARPO, "total": 27, "topic_id": 2415, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/462645dermatology.png], ["deck": SARPO, "total": 22, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/7845414anesthysia.png, "completed": , "title": Anesthesia, "topic_id": 2639], ["topic_id": 2406, "total": 31, "title": Radiology, "deck": SARPO, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5468718radiology.png, "completed": ], ["title": Psychiatry, "total": 26, "topic_id": 2410, "deck": SARPO, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2301599psychiatry.png, "completed": ], ["deck": SARPO, "completed": , "topic_id": 2414, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/2994784orthopendics.png, "title": Orthopaedics, "total": 35]], "Clinicals": [["title": Medicine, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5520806medicine.png, "topic_id": 2637, "total": 137, "deck": Clinicals, "completed": ], ["title": Surgery, "deck": Clinicals, "topic_id": 2638, "total": 83, "completed": , "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/5084703surgery.png], ["topic_id": 2423, "sub_img_url": , "deck": Clinicals, "title": Obg&Gy, "completed": , "total": 41], ["sub_img_url": , "topic_id": 2246, "title": Paediatrics, "deck": Clinicals, "completed": , "total": 27]], "Preclinicals": [["title": Anatomy, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1513449anatomy.png, "completed": , "topic_id": 2243, "deck": Preclinicals, "total": 47], ["total": 59, "title": Physiology, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/1524143physiology.png, "completed": , "topic_id": 2421, "deck": Preclinicals], ["total": 35, "deck": Preclinicals, "completed": , "title": Biochemistry, "sub_img_url": http://d1wspjxps4juxd.cloudfront.net/course_file_meta/3658439biochemistry.png, "topic_id": 2245]]]
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: Current Screenshot 1]

[image: Current Screenshot 2]

Any way how to achieve this data so that my grouping sequence is in the form of

["Preclinicals", "Paraclinicals", "Clinicals (Prefinals)", "Clinicals", "SARPO"].

i.e. The 1st section is Preclinicals and there rows, 2nd section is Paraclinicals and there rows, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries are by definition, unordered.

Comment: Shorten your question and remove irrelevant information. It looks to me like you already have the answer, use the array you listed at the end and loop over it and get the values from your dictionary in that order.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But how??

Comment: @Magnas yes but any how I need this in sorted form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you research and use `Codable` instead for your json decoding and work with structures so your code will be clearer and easier to work with.

Assuming you do and you would have a custom type similar to the below (what you have posted isn't proper json so I have made some assumptions)

```
struct Topic: Decodable {
    let topicId: Int
    let completed: String
    let deck: String
    let subImageUrl: String
    let title: String
    let total: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case topicId = "topic_id"
        case subImageUrl = "sub_img_url"
        case completed, deck, title, total
    }
}
```

Then we can wrap this struct in another custom type that fits your UI requirements with a deck (I call them section here) name and an array of topics

```
struct TopicSection {
    let section: String
    let topics: [Topic]
}
```

So if you have all your topics from the json in an array `topics` you can then create an array of this new struct where the content comes in the order specified in your dec/section names array.

```
let sectionNames = ["Preclinicals", "Paraclinicals", "Clinicals (Prefinals)", "Clinicals", "SARPO"]

var sections = [TopicSection]()

sectionNames.forEach { name in
    let section = TopicSection(section: name, topics: topics.filter { $0.deck == name})
    sections.append(section)
}
```

And then you can use the `sections` array as the source for your table view. Of course the `TopicSection` could also be used even without using `Codable` by changing the type of `topics` to be a dictionary, [String: Any]

Comment: Thanks for this but my sectionNames are dynamic.

Comment: @SatishThakur Then how do you define the sort order?

Comment: @SatishThakur any feedback on this?